Amazon Aurora RDS - invalid undo record
Context
Aurora RDS, MySQL 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.05.2
Problem
The writer instance is constantly cycling. In the AWS RDS console, under Logs & events for the writer, I see
Attempting to restart the database with zero downtime.
Attempt to restart the database with zero downtime finished. The process took 2253 ms, 28 connections preserved, 0 connections dropped. See the database error log for details.

The readers are fine; no restart logging in Logs & events.
In mysql-error.log, I see
ERROR: Found invalid undo record! Undo record len=18446744073709543964, rec_offset=7652, next_rec_offset=0 
...
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-11-14T23:47:13Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=82a011aba84a660d4bf03c9af2fb1fe3233b0bc1
Thread pointer: 0x4000498ec000
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...

When I failover and promote a new writer, the old writer -- now a reader -- comes up fine and stays up. The new writer immediately starts restarting.
Running mysqlcheck shows ok for everything I've checked.
Based on some light Googling, it's suggested that you can use innodb_force_recovery but it's not clear to me where I can even set that in Aurora -- it's not in the parameter group for the cluster. The warnings about it also scare me as this is a production system.
Questions
What are my options? It's my understanding that the undo log cycles. Can I simply wait this out? Interestingly, I can still write to the database and the changes show up on the reader instances so updates and replication is still happening. If I'm to proceed with innodb_force_recovery, where do I set this? Using set @innodb_force_recovery = ... in an interactive session on the writer?

Ultimately, unfortunately this required us reaching out to AWS support (and paying the 10% Business Support Plan tithe).
They determined that there was corruption in undo records associated with one of our indexes and it was surfacing during InnoDB's purge process. They disabled purge and restarted the instance allowing us to drop the impacted index and recreate it. They followed up by reenabling purge.
